# Friends Invite for Facebook HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

How can i add in my facebook application invite friends.

First of all i use actionscript, in order to handle invite issue i searched so many sites but i ve got nothing, cuz facebook doesn't support invite actions. then i learnt that JavaScript can handle this, however i couldn't find anything valuable about that

Answer (score 0):

don't worry, when some years ago i faced javascript for the first time it was absolutely clear because it's AS2.0 only without all that drawing featurs but with regexp